# Spring Security (OAuth): How can I add a request header when restTemplate is not exposed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to set up a Resource server using the built-in OAuth support in Spring Security. I need to inject a new request header into every request that is sent from the Resource server to the Auth service. How can I do that?

**Use case**

The Auth service sits behind a corporate API Gateway forwarding service, like so:

```
Resource API > API Gateway > Auth API
```

Every request sent through the API Gateway requires an additional header to authenticate the client to the Gateway service. How can I inject this header? The Auth API implementation is otherwise a standard OIDC setup.

**My setup**

I have added spring security oauth2 to my Gradle build:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose'
```

I have configured the issuer URI in Spring Security, as follows:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://auth/api/url
```

**The problem**

On app startup, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://auth/api/url"
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:99) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
```

Debugging the code for `JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils`, I see that it's failing because the API Gateway header is missing from the configuration request.

The problem is, I don't know how to modify the configuration utils to inject the API Gateway header. The request is built inline, using the URI only:

```
                RequestEntity<Void> request = RequestEntity.get(uri).build();
                ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> response = rest.exchange(request, STRING_OBJECT_MAP);
                Map<String, Object> configuration = response.getBody();
```

The RestTemplate is hidden from my app code, so I don't see a way to add a client interceptor:

```
    private static final RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
```

In fact, the entire config utils class is package-level access, so I really can't do anything with it:

```
final class JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils {
```

Everything else about the OIDC solution should be standard. How can I inject the required header without reinventing the entire Spring Security Oauth solution and all of the automagical configuration that it does?

Answer (score 0):

All of the configurations enabled by setting any of the following properties:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri:
          jwk-set-uri:
          jws-algorithm:
          public-key-location:
```

ultimately end up causing a `JwtDecoder` bean to be created and automatically configured by Spring Boot (see `OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.JwtDecoderConfiguration` in the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure` jar).

The easiest way to take control of this process and avoid the error would be to provide your own bean:

```
@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    // ...
}
```

You could use the code in `JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils` as a starting point and add your own header to your own `RestTemplate`, or you can simply provide an implementation directly and skip calling out to your auth server.